# For each of the following sets, determine if it is open, closed, compact

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I can't figure out how to prove if a set is closed or open. I understand that a set is closed if and only if it contains all its points of accumulation and the rest of the theory. But, I can't actually solve the exercises.

1. $A = \{(x,y,z)|e^{(x \cdot y)} + z^2 \le 2\}$
2. $A = \{(x,y)|x+y^3  \gt 0 , x \gt 0, y \lt 0\}$

Comment: Note that the word '*group*' is not used as synonym for '*set*' in mathematics, what you intended to write. Also please, correct your formulas. Is $z^2$ still in the exponent?

Comment: Hi. thank you. no $z^2$ is not in the exponent...How can I write this well?

Comment: Typesetting tip: You should enclose each complete formula in `$` instead of individual parts. TeX uses `{` and `}` for grouping, so use those to put multiple symbols in the exponent. Because these are used for grouping, you will have to use `\{` and `\}` to produce $\{$ and $\}$ for your sets.

Comment: As for your exercises: Did you study the relation between openess, closedness and continuity yet (“A function $f$ is continuous if the preimage of every open set is …” an so on)? If you have, try to write your sets as preimages of intervals of $\mathbb{R}$ (or an intersection of such preimages for the second one). For compactness you might have had the criterion that a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded.

Comment: Typesetting. If you want $e^{xy}$ type: e^{xy} It is usually a bad idea to use * for multiplication and you need curly brackets if you are trying to superscript more than one character.

Comment: For 2. you might ask: (1) is (0,0) an accumulation point? And is the set bounded?

Comment: I removed the [tag:topological-groups] tag. Please read the tag summary when using a tag.

Answer (score 1):

There are other, arguably simplier, ways to detect whether a set is open or closed. For example if $f:X\to Y$ is continuous then for any closed/open $A\subset Y$ we have $f^{-1}(A)$ is closed/open.

How can you apply it here? Take for example

$$f:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}$$
$$f(x,y,z)=e^{xy}+z^2$$

It is a matter of basic analysis to show that $f$ is continuous. With that note that your $A$ in point 1 is equal to $A=f^{-1}((-\infty,2])$ and obviously $(-\infty, 2]$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$.

Point 2 is done analogously except that you need 3 functions and need to use the fact that intersection/union of finite family of open/closed subsets is again open/closed.